# Why do we ask why others have died?

Tags: death

When someone dies, one of the first questions people usually are concerned about is how he/she died?

What are the reasons to know the causes of someone's death?

Comment: I don't think this is true.  For example, if someone spent the last ten years in a long-term care facility with declining condition from dementia, or in a hospital fighting cancer, then I don't think anyone will ask.  On the other hand, if someone breaks a leg, wins money, gets fired or promoted, breaks up with someone, or have anything major unexpected happen to them, then I would expect questions about that.

Comment: I think answers to this question will be matters of opinion rather than fact. There can be many reasons for asking why they died. It could be curiosity, it could be concern for familial genetic links which could indicate potential issues with others, it could be the thought that they may have had a hand in their death.... so many concerns and possibilities